# Kafka Streams: Implement a simple KeyValueStore where I can put and get data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka streams application which operates on the incoming state and need to store the state before writing to the next topic. The write should occur only after  the state is updated in local store.

Something like this.

```
stream.map(this::getAndUpdateState)
          .map(this::processStateAndEvent)
          .to("topicname");
```

So that in `getAndUpdateState()` I can do like

```
state = store.get(key); // or new if null
state = updateState(state, event);  // update changes to state
store.put(key, state);  // write back the state
return state;
```

How do I implement that simple get() and put() operation on a kafka store? I already tried using [KeyValueStore](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/KeyValueStore.html) but it had issues as I had to add it a source and sink processor and all.

Alternatively, a way to get and put in kafka using a KTable or some other concept is also fine.

Comment: Not sure why `KeyValue`Store will not help in your case. I would suggest to use the `transform(...)` method instead of `map(...)`. Since `transform` is for stateful operations. Have you seen this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/StateStoresInTheDSLIntegrationTest.java#L106 ?

Comment: What type of object is `state`? It appears you want to have some `groupByKey` operation here or just a compacted topic thats storing the latest key

Comment: @user152568  KeyValueStore needs a processor topology to be initiated and be added to that along with source and sink processors. And it was not working properly when I tried it. Can you elaborate further on how it might work?..  I will look into transform and update question.

Comment: @cricket_007 

state is an object that's storable in Kafka, something that extends **SpecificRecord**. I already tried using **groupByKey()** and then aggregating, 

but the issue is we can't make the **processStateAndEvent** run sequentially after aggregation as they are executing asynchronously.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] of the code and events you are trying to process?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @cricket_007, Unfortunately, I don't have a code snippet ready since it is part of a large project. I will try to replicate the same issue in a minimal example and share. Once again thank you!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax , basically, I want to implement a stateful stream processing topology in Kafka where I can make sure the state is stored and available before next processor is running. Is it clear now? what is the missing part?

Comment: Follow up question: Why do you want/need to build the state first? Compare my answer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I want to build the state first so that state can be used to construct the outgoing message. So that I won't have to do the same state changes at two places (once before adding state, and once for processing outgoing)

Comment: @user152468 I tried that example and it seems like exactly what I want, however right now stuck with the values that I **stateStore.get()** being null most of the times. There is no error or something and the value actually exists in some case. Is the **StateStore.put()** a non-blocking call which might have caused raise to a race condition between put and get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for suggestions from [user152468](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753789/kafka-streams-implement-a-simple-keyvaluestore-where-i-can-put-and-get-data#comment92437229_52753789) and [Matthias J. Sax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783572/5106170) .

I was able to do stateful processing within kafka streams using `transform()` method. A full working code based on the original Pipe example is given below.

Pipe.java :

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Stores;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Pipe{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        //  setting Configs
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        // initializing  a streambuilder for building topology.
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        // creating a KStream that is continuously generating records from its source kafka topic "streams-plaintext-output"
        KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");

        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Long>> wordCountsStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("WordCountsStore"),
                Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.Long())
                .withCachingEnabled();

        builder.addStateStore(wordCountsStore);

        source.map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair("key", v))
                .peek((k, s) -> System.out.printf("After keying: %s, value: %s\n", k, s))
                .transform(new SampleTransformSupplier(wordCountsStore.name()), wordCountsStore.name())
                .peek((k, s) -> System.out.printf("After transform: %s, value: %s\n", k, s));
        // writing this source to another kafka topic "streams-pipe-output"
        source.to("streams-pipe-output");
        // generating the topology
        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        System.out.print(topology.describe());

        // constructing a streams client with the properties and topology
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attaching shutdown handler
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try{
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e){
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static class SampleTransformSupplier implements TransformerSupplier<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> {

        final private String stateStoreName;

        public SampleTransformSupplier(String stateStoreName) {
            this.stateStoreName = stateStoreName;
        }

        @Override
        public Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> get() {
            return new Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>() {


                private KeyValueStore<String, Long> stateStore;

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
                    stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Long>) processorContext.getStateStore(stateStoreName);
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
                    Long countSoFar = stateStore.get(key);
                    if(countSoFar == null){
                        System.out.print("Initializing count so far. this message should be printed only once");
                        countSoFar = 0L;
                    }
                    countSoFar += value.length();
                    System.out.printf(" Key: %s, Value: %s, Count: %d\n\n", key, value, countSoFar);
                    stateStore.put(key, countSoFar);
                    return KeyValue.pair(key, value);
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                    // No need to close as this is handled by kafka.
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do batch processing. Kafka Streams is a stream processing library and all processor run in parallel/concurrently building a data pipeline.

I guess you could still use `transform()` with attached state and don't emit anything downstream but only put data into the store. You can than schedule a wall-clock time punctuation to scan the whole store and emit all data in the store downstream. However, overall this seems to be an anti-pattern.

The hard part to figure out thought is, when is the state "fully loaded" -- because a topic is by definition/conceptually infinite, loading the state will "never" be finished.

Comment: No, It's not batch processing. I just want the state updation and the outgoing transformation to be strictly sequential. Probably I am overthinking it with the state store and all. Maybe there is a better apporach to this. How is stateful sequential processing usually handled in Kafka?

Comment: I looked into transformValues(). Seems like that is exactly what I want. 

So I went ahead and implemented a **ValueTransformerWithKey** which also stores the state to StateStore. But unfortunately, the **stateStore.get()** is returning null most of the times. Is there any reason behind this or am I overlooking something?..    There are no errors being thrown or something and the state is actually there sometimes, but not always. 

Is there something like a race condition or non blocking call which delays the **put()** call?

Comment: Not sure how you create the state. Can you update your question with the code? In general, you need to put data into the state in your own code. When you start a new application, the state will be empty initially.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for all the help, I could achieve the desired effect by using **transform()** method. I've posted the solution as a separate answer.